# Resharper - Showing inconclusive tests as inconclusive rather than failed?

Tags: resharper, automated-tests, mstest

Does anyone know if there is a way to show inconclusive tests in resharper as inconclusive rather than failed? i would like to keep tests that still need to be implemented aside from test that are failing due to a bug.

Comment: Which version of ReSharper are you using, and which test framework are you using to write your tests? We use R# 5.1 and NUnit, and my experience has been that `Assert.Inconclusive()` does make the test show up yellow in the R# test runner.

Comment: @Joe R#5.1 shows failure when running MS Tests with Assert.Inconclusive().

Comment: Yeah we are using MSTest

Answer (score -2):

With `MSTest`, you can apply the `Ignore` attribute and the test runners will ignore the test (and labelled it as 'ignored', rather than 'inconclusive').

This allows you to put placeholders/ partly implemented/ ignore broken tests.

e.g

```
[Ignore]
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(true);
}
```

will not produce a failed test, but will be ignored.

Comment: Ignore will also mean it could be forgotten.